# xticks and bar plot showing at different positions in the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I have a dictionary names dc in which I have some keys and values. I want to plot the dictionary based on the top 10 values in the dictionary.

I have successfully done with sorting out the dictionary and plotting a bar graph using it. but when I try to set xticks, xticks get separated with the bar graph.

Here is my code:

```
dc = {0: 7, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 5, 4: 7, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3, 15: 4, 16: 6, 17: 6, 18: 9, 19: 9, 20: 3, 21: 5, 22: 11, 23: 5, 24: 15, 25: 6, 26: 6, 27: 11, 28: 7, 29: 60, 30: 10, 31: 8, 32: 10, 33: 6, 34: 6, 35: 11, 36: 11, 37: 1, 38: 5, 39: 5, 40: 6, 41: 2, 42: 6, 43: 1, 44: 3, 45: 5, 47: 1, 48: 6, 49: 4, 50: 5, 51: 2, 52: 3, 53: 1, 54: 3, 55: 1, 56: 2, 58: 3, 60: 2, 62: 2, 63: 2, 80: 1}
dc_sorted = sorted(dc.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
key_10 = [dc_sorted[i][0] for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
value_10= [dc_sorted[i][1] for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
for index in range(len(key_10)):
    plt.bar(key_10[index],value_10[index],color ='blue')
    plt.text(key_10[index],value_10[index],str(value_10[index]),color="green")
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(key_10)),key_10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use numbers for the x-axis, `plt.bar` will use these as an x-position. If you use strings, the bars are just put one after another. Internally they will be numbered `0,1,2,...`

Note that the default width of the bars is 0.8, which is measured in x-coordinates. If your numbers are far apart, bars with numeric x-axis will also be far apart and appear narrow.

Here is a comparison between both ways:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dc = {0: 7, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 5, 4: 7, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3, 15: 4, 16: 6, 17: 6, 18: 9, 19: 9, 20: 3, 21: 5, 22: 11, 23: 5, 24: 15, 25: 6, 26: 6, 27: 11, 28: 7, 29: 60, 30: 10, 31: 8, 32: 10, 33: 6, 34: 6, 35: 11, 36: 11, 37: 1, 38: 5, 39: 5, 40: 6, 41: 2, 42: 6, 43: 1, 44: 3, 45: 5, 47: 1, 48: 6, 49: 4, 50: 5, 51: 2, 52: 3, 53: 1, 54: 3, 55: 1, 56: 2, 58: 3, 60: 2, 62: 2, 63: 2, 80: 1}
dc_sorted = sorted(dc.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8))

# numeric keys
key_10 = [dc_sorted[i][0] for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
value_10 = [dc_sorted[i][1] for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
ax1.bar(key_10, value_10, color='blue')
for key, value in zip(key_10, value_10):
    ax1.text(key, value, f'{value}\n', color="green", ha='center', va='center')
ax1.set_xticks(key_10)
ax1.set_title('numeric keys')

# keys converted to string
key_10 = [str(dc_sorted[i][0]) for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
ax2.bar(key_10, value_10, color='blue')
for key, value in zip(key_10, value_10):
    ax2.text(key, value, f'{value}\n', color="green", ha='center', va='center')
ax2.set_xticks(range(len(key_10)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(key_10)
ax2.set_title('keys converted to string')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: With `ha='center'` text can be horizontally centered. And with `va='center'` and adding a newline into the string, the text would be put nicely on top of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

The x in barplot takes the position of the bar you want to plot in the figure. In you code you provide the value of the key. So your ticks are plotted at 0-9, but your bars are plotted at the value of the keys.
Also for barplot you can pass an array instead of plotting one bar at a time.

```
dc = {0: 7, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 5, 4: 7, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 2, 9: 2, 11: 1, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3, 15: 4, 16: 6, 17: 6, 18: 9, 19: 9, 20: 3, 21: 5, 22: 11, 23: 5, 24: 15, 25: 6, 26: 6, 27: 11, 28: 7, 29: 60, 30: 10, 31: 8, 32: 10, 33: 6, 34: 6, 35: 11, 36: 11, 37: 1, 38: 5, 39: 5, 40: 6, 41: 2, 42: 6, 43: 1, 44: 3, 45: 5, 47: 1, 48: 6, 49: 4, 50: 5, 51: 2, 52: 3, 53: 1, 54: 3, 55: 1, 56: 2, 58: 3, 60: 2, 62: 2, 63: 2, 80: 1}
dc_sorted = sorted(dc.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
key_10 = [dc_sorted[i][0] for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
value_10= [dc_sorted[i][1] for i in range(len(dc_sorted))][:10]
plt.bar(np.arange(len(key_10)),value_10, color ='blue')
for index in range(len(key_10)):
    plt.text(index,value_10[index],str(value_10[index]),color="green")
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(key_10)),key_10)
plt.show()
```

[image]